# Find file by name up the directory tree, using bash

Tags: bash, find

Using `bash`, how can I find a file with a specific name somewhere up the directory tree from the `pwd`?

To be more clear. I want to find a file that sits in my working directory's root, but I don't know where the root is, and my `pwd` might be anywhere below the root.

Comment: What do you mean you don't know where your root is? Can you give a short example of how your directory tree looks like? What is your current working directory and where you want to search for files? Generally, to search everywhere, you can run `find / -name <filename>` as a `root` user.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Find `file.txt` up to root

```
x=`pwd`
while [ "$x" != "/" ] ; do
    x=`dirname "$x"`
    find "$x" -maxdepth 1 -name file.txt
done
```

Comment: Great stuff @kev. I just added a break to the loop:

``x=`pwd`; while [ "$x" != "/" ] ; do x=`dirname "$x"`; echo "$x"; if [ `find "$x" -maxdepth 1 -name erm.properties` ]; then break; fi; done``

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. It just keeps doing the while over and over forever. The x is going from current path to "/" but after that it just starts all over.

Comment: Never mind. My problem stemmed from making an alias and then calling the alias within the alias.

Comment: nice, you could also use   if [ -f "$x/erm.properties" ]  .. instead of the find.

Answer (score 10):

```
local DIR=$(pwd)
while [ ! -z "$DIR" ] && [ ! -f "$DIR/myFile.txt" ]; do
    DIR="${DIR%\/*}"
done
echo $DIR/myFile.txt
```

Comment: Nice and terse solution :+1:

Comment: Sometimes it makes more sense to follow the realpath instead of the links. In this case replace the first line with:`DIR=$(realpath $PWD)`

Answer (score 4):

I have the following function defined in my ~/.bashrc:

```
dnif () { 
    # Recursively list a file from PWD up the directory tree to root
    [[ -n $1 ]] || { echo "dnif [ls-opts] name"; return 1; }
    local THERE=$PWD RC=2
    while [[ $THERE != / ]]
        do [[ -e $THERE/${2:-$1} ]] && { ls ${2:+$1} $THERE/${2:-$1}; RC=0; }
            THERE=$(dirname $THERE)
        done
    [[ -e $THERE/${2:-$1} ]] && { ls ${2:+$1} /${2:-$1}; RC=0; }
    return $RC
}
```

which will search for a name you provide as a parameter in each directory upwards from the current to the root, and if found, list it with 'ls' and the optional ls -options that you provide. Example output:

```
me@host:~/dev/example
$ dnif; echo $?
dnif [ls-opts] name
1
me@host:~/dev/example
$ dnif -alp nonesuch; echo $?
2
me@host:~/dev/example
$ dnif -alp .bashrc; echo $?
-rw-r--r-- 1 me mine 3486 Apr  3  2012 /home/me/.bashrc
0
me@host:~/dev/example
$ dnif -d .
/home/me/dev/example/.
/home/me/dev/.
/home/me/.
/home/.
/.
```

Please note:

- "dnif" is "find" backwards.
- The function is a finite loop (not recursive), creates no subshells, and uses Bash built-ins as much as possible for speed.
- All hits at each ascending directory level are listed.
- The ls -opts are optional, but must precede the required search argument.
- The search argument may be a file or directory.
- If the search argument is a directory, include the ls -opt '-d' to restrict the results to directory names rather than contents.
- The function returns exit code

  - 0 if there is at least one hit,
  - 1 if no parameters are provided for help, and
  - 2 if nothing is found.