# bashrc alias for not confusing git and mercurial

Tags: git, bash, mercurial, alias

Scenario: I prefer Mercurial but I often have to deal with git repositories so I end up using both of them on a daily basis. As such I often type:

```
hg commit -m "message"
```

...where instead I want:

```
git commit -am "message"
```

...and vice versa.

I would like my bashrc file to be smart enough so that it can detect this kind of confusion by pre-emptively checking whether the directory I'm in has a ".git" or ".hg" directory and "fix" the syntax in accordance.

Basically I think what I'm looking for is a way to override both commands via a bash function (I know how to do that) and somehow check whether the first part of the command starts with "hg ci -m" or "git ci -am" (this I don't know).

I'm not sure whether bashrc aliases/functions can be extended to such a level of expressiveness but I'm sure I'm not the only one being bitten by this "confusion" so I wonder if someone already came up with a solution.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: +1 Very good question. Unfortunately, I don't have any answers for you.

Comment: Rather than making use of such ugly hacks, you might consider using the shell readline history feature.

Comment: Writing a shell script that performs the basic version control operations using the correct system (based on the repository in the current directory) hardly seems like an "ugly hack" to me.

Comment: readline history sounds promising: can you elaborate more?

Comment: Several more items to consider: (1) you might be in a subdirectory, so there is no `.hg` nor `.git` in `$PWD`, but one of `git` or `hg` is still correct. (2) You might have a git repo inside an hg-controlled tree, or vice versa, so that *both* commands are possible.  (You can avoid case (2) by just not doing that, of course; it's just something I do, so I have it all the time. :-) )

Comment: You could also use hg-git and simply work in Mercurial for all repositories. It works very well.

Comment: I opened a bug request on mercurial bug tracker asking for an "-a" option for "hg commit" which does nothing: http://bz.selenic.com/show_bug.cgi?id=4225

Comment: @torek good points, although as to me - i don't recall when I found myself last in a subdirectory in a project (I used to use sublime - and would open the whole dir, now using vim - again, open it in root dir of the project). I guess one could search up the tree for .git or .hg, something along the lines of this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9377073/1592915, and search for first match of .hg or .git - that would avoid the second problem too, no?

Comment: In my case it wouldn't help the second problem, as I sometimes want to commit specifically to one repo or the other (the "inner" ones are private and the "outer" ones are shared, in my case).  That's a weird situation, admittedly.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know enough about `hg` to suggest how to rewrite commands, but here are some convenience functions for you:

```
is_git_repo() { command git rev-parse --git-dir &> /dev/null; }
is_hg_repo() { command hg root &> /dev/null; }
```

Example usage:

```
git() { 
  if is_hg_repo
  then
    echo "This is is a hg repo, you silly goose!"
    return 1
  else
    command git "$@"
  fi
}

hg() { 
  if is_git_repo
  then
    echo "Surely you're joking... this is git repo!"
    return 1
  else
    command hg "$@"
  fi
}
```

Comment: This is not very useful in practice as it only changes the error message you get (as opposed to "doing the right thing").

Comment: @GiampaoloRodolà Well what about just modifying this snippet to suit your needs instead of complaining that it is not 100% what you are looking for....

Comment: I'm simply stating that this is not what I was looking for *at all* (the question was different). is_git_repo() and is_hg_repo() functions are a valuable contribution though, hence my upvote for you.

Answer (score 1):

How about making a script to check for existence of `.git` or `.hg` directories, and then in your `.bashrc` just aliasing a common command to run the script?

As it's a matter of choosing one or the other, maybe something along the lines of

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -d ./.git ]
  then
    cmd='git commit -am '
  else
    cmd='hg commit -m '
fi

cmd=$cmd+$1
echo $cmd
$cmd
```

save it as `~/.scripts/commit.sh`, and add an alias to bashrc

`alias commit='~/.scripts/commit.sh'`

Now when you want to commit, just use `commit 'awesome bugfixes'` and it will echo and run the proper command for you.