# How do I find (using bash) the top-level file with a particular name within a directory path?

Tags: bash, shell, find

I have a bash script that runs mysql scripts and that takes the mysql database name from a file rather than having me type in it as an option (so that I won't mistakenly type in the wrong one).  I set this by putting the mysql database name within a file called mysql_db_name that is either in the same directory as the script I'm running or somewhere above that directory in its directory path: it could be in the parent directory, the parent's parent etc.  This bash script runs a mysql script when I type:

```
bash_script mysql_script_name
```

I would like to have my bash script find the top-level file caled mysql_db_name within the path of the mysql_script_name script.

My current code snippet to do this is:

```
MFILE=`find / -exec bash -c '[[ $PWD != "$1"* ]]' bash {} \; -prune -name mysql_db_name -print`
```

This usually works, but not if there is another directory in the parent directory with a file called mysql_db_name whose directory name is a subset of the current directory name.  For example, if this exists:

```
parent/directory1/mysql_db_name
parent/directory11/mysql_db_name
parent/directory11/mysql_script_name.sql
```

Then if I try to run `mysql_script_name` in `directory11` the bash_script will fail.  It would not fail if `directory1` above was instead named `directory2`.

This problem is similar to [Find file by name up the directory tree, using bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376904/find-file-by-name-up-the-directory-tree-using-bash) but I can't get those solutions to work.

Comment: Why are you using `$PWD`? That's not the directory containing the script, it's your current directory.

Comment: Do you mean the same directory as `bash_script` or the same directory as `mysql_script_name.sql`?

Comment: AND you're starting this from the `/` (root) directory? I don't see how this can save you anytime, searching thru `/bin, /boot, /dev, /etc` (maybe more, (maybe less) ),  before getting the `/home`.  Also, your terminology is confusing, i.e. *" find the top-level file caled mysql_db_name within the path of the mysql_script_name script"*. You have included a sample file layout, but unclear how your `find` command is to work in that context. Consider adding `cd /path/to/start; find . -exec bash -c ....`  to your debugging version. You can go back to `/` once we see a simpler version work.GoodLuck

Comment: $PWD works because I always run the script from the directory containing the script, so in this case they are always the same.  If the two were different then I would indeed want the directory containing mysql_script.sql, not the directory containing bash_script (which is $HOME/bin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the file name and the directory path it's in, there is no sane reason to use `find` here anyway.

```
path='/'
for dir in path to deepest possible dir containing the file; do
    path=$path/$dir
    test -e "$path/mysql_db_name" && break
done
test -e "$path/mysql_db_name" || { echo "$0: mysql_db_name not found" >&2; exit 2;}
: proceed to use "$path/mysql_db_name"
```

This proceeds forward to find the highest directory with a file with that name. It should not be hard to see how to turn it around to start from the deepest directory; here is one approach.

```
path=/path/to/deepest/possible/dir/containing/the/file
while [ "$path" ]; do
    test -e "$path/mysql_db_name" && break
    path=${path%/*}
done
test -e "$path/mysql_db_name" || { echo "$0: mysql_db_name not found" >&2; exit 2;}
: proceed to use "$path/mysql_db_name"
```

Comment: Thanks -- not sure how to set up the for loop condition in the top example, but the bottom one works and I guess I don't mind finding the deepest level named file rather than the top level one.  I'll mark it as solved.

Comment: It's the same path, only without the slashes beweeen the directory names. So if your real path is `/home/you/Desktop/project/mysql_db_name` you'd say `for dir in home you Desktop project` or perhaps even `for dir in home/you Desktop project` to skip the `/home` level.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that the directory tree is not infinitely deep, a shell helper function that we can call recursively would be useful, and it should work the same in zsh & bash:

```bash
find_files_in_dir_branch() {
  # if there is a regular file in this dir, print its full path
  [ -f "$1" ] && readlink -f "$PWD/$1"

  # if we have reached the root dir, finish with an error
  if [ "$PWD" = / ] ; then 
    false
  # otherwise, run same function in a subshell, in parent dir
  else 
    (cd .. ; find_files_in_dir_branch "$1")
  fi 
}

find_farthest_file_named() {
  local candidates="$(find_files_in_dir_branch $1)"
  # are there any canditates at all? then print the last/farthest one
  [ -n "$candidates" ] && tail -1 <<< "$candidates"
}

# invoke as find_farthest_file_named [something]
```

It's a bit long to turn into a oneliner - it is practical to put it in a functions anyway because we can easily see if they exit with code `1` when nothing found.

Example usage:

```
/# mkdir -p /h/a/y/stack ### test dir structure
/# touch /needle /h/a/needle /h/a/y/stack/needle ### 3 needles in haystack
/# cd /h/a/y/stack/
/h/a/y/stack# find_farthest_file_named needle ; echo $? ### find root one and succeed
/needle
0
/h/a/y/stack# rm /needle 
/h/a/y/stack# find_farthest_file_named needle ; echo $? ### find middle one and succeed
/h/a/needle
0
/h/a/y/stack# rm /h/a/needle
/h/a/y/stack# find_farthest_file_named needle ; echo $? ### find last one and succeed
/h/a/y/stack/needle
0
/h/a/y/stack# rm needle 
/h/a/y/stack# find_farthest_file_named needle ; echo $? ### find none and fail
/h/a/y/stack# echo $?
1
```

Comment: Running the recursive case in a subshell is kind of iffy. It would probably make more sense to pass the directory as a variable and leave the current working directory alone.

Comment: Also, the OP seems to want the most distant, not the nearest match.

Comment: Okay I re-read the "the top level"_ sentence twice! Thanks for pointing it out @tripleee. "The top level directory is the directory closest to the root" 

Comment: I can't create directory names that match the database names because the scripts may (for various reasons) be in subdirectories of the top-level directory for programs dealing with the database.  Also, that top-level directory is not always the same distance along the path away from root.

Comment: Updated answer according to new understanding of what was desired